# Ansible Playbook Fails when Executed Through Jenkins after upgrade

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

After upgradig jenkins to version 2.387.3 I have an error invoking an ansible playbook and passing extraVars to it.

The declarative pipeline fragment

```
ansiblePlaybook([ 
        become: false, 
        colorized: true, 
        installation: 'ansible', 
        extraVars: [
            login: 'mylogin',
            secret_key: [value: 'g4dfKWENpeF6pY05', hidden: true]
        ],                      
        playbook: 'src/main/ansible/prova_parametri.yml'
   ])
```

The error is:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class hudson.util.Secret (java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; hudson.util.Secret is in unnamed module of loader org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader @76908cc0)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ansible.workflow.AnsiblePlaybookStep$AnsiblePlaybookExecution.convertExtraVars(AnsiblePlaybookStep.java:390)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ansible.workflow.AnsiblePlaybookStep$AnsiblePlaybookExecution.run(AnsiblePlaybookStep.java:422)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ansible.workflow.AnsiblePlaybookStep$AnsiblePlaybookExecution.run(AnsiblePlaybookStep.java:352)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1$1.call(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
at hudson.security.ACL.impersonate2(ACL.java:451)
at hudson.security.ACL.impersonate(ACL.java:463)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1.run(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:44)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Comment: Smells like a plugin which is not compatible with your jenkins version... Make sure your plugins are up to date.

Comment: Downgrading Ansible plugin to version 148.v6b_13c6de3a_47 fixed the problem.
Jenkins signals that this plugin should be upgraded for security reasons

Comment: I'have opened a ticket https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-71286

Answer (score 0):

This issue was fixed with release of ansible-plugin version 215.v1c78933a_b_0d7

Reference:
[Release 215.v1c78933a_b_0d7](https://github.com/jenkinsci/ansible-plugin/releases/tag/215.v1c78933a_b_0d7)